Travel from Berlin to Tunis without flight?
Is it possible? Have you done it?
There seem to be ferries from Italy and France to Tunis (Marseille, Genova, Roma, Salerno, Palermo).
How are the connecting trains from Germany to these places?
How long does the journey take in total?
How is the procedure upon arrival in Tunis?

You're asking a lot of questions. Could you edit your question and try to focus on a single, answerable, question? And please also add information about what you have found out by yourself already. You can create separate questions if you want to ask more.

You should probably also take the tour, if you haven't done that already

See Rome2Rio which shows ferries from Marseilles, Milan, Rome and Palermo.

Maybe focus on the last question, ferry embarkation/disembarkation, port accessibility, etc.? It seems you already mostly found the list of potential ferries, train connections can be looked up everywhere including bahn.de and are not really a good question for this site.

We're not a travel agency, here. But, yes, it is possible. Easy, even.
Taking Berlin as a starting point, you could do...

Berlin to Munich by train.
Munich to Milan by bus.
Milan to Rome by train.
Rome to Civitavecchia by train.
Civitavecchia to Tunis by ferry.

I've done each of these legs at different times in my life.
Not affiliated, but Rome2Rio now can show you nicely segmented journeys. Spend 5 minutes, and you'll learn all you need to know.
